# Add static javascript to every page of joomla

Tags: joomla

Im completely new to Joomla development. I need to develop Joomla plugin that adds static javascript to the footer of all the pages of a Joomla site. Also, the plugin would need to save 2 fields in database, and access these fields on per page basis. Also, Admin panel is needed.

Now, my questoion is, where do i start? Joomla plugin development is a big task, so if I can get some pointers as to where to start, it would be very supporting.

Im not asking for direct code, but just the right direction to start.

Thanx in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Joomla has three types of extensions (what you refered to as plugin): components, modules and plugins, where each has a different purpose.

If you need to add javascript to all pages, the best place is your template. If you don't have access to template, just building an extension, then you have to create a **content [plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin)**.

If you need to create extension with admin panel which also works with database, you need to create a **component**. The best place to get started is tutorial [Developing a MVC component for Joomla 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5)

Comment: Thnax @Marko D ... This is what I was looking for. "What" to look for to start. Thnx you soo much.